# Python AST exec "... is not defined" error on recursive function

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I came across this error

```
def test_rec():
    import ast
    exec(compile(ast.fix_missing_locations(ast.parse("""
def fact(n):
    return 1 if n == 0 else n * fact(n - 1)

print(fact(5))
"""), "<string>", "exec")))
```

This yield this error, which is weird

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gecko/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/lampy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/gecko/code/lampycode/tests/test_let_lang.py", line 6, in test_rec
    exec(compile(ast.fix_missing_locations(ast.parse("""
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in fact
NameError: name 'fact' is not defined
```

If I copy and paste the same code in REPL it works fine

```
>>> def fact(n):
...     return 1 if n == 0 else n * fact(n - 1)
... 
>>> print(fact(5))
120
>>>
```

Any ideas?

I could reduce the problem further here is the minimal exempla, this would overflow the stack but it gives me the same not defined error

```
def test_rec3():
    exec("""
def f():
    f()

f()
""")
```

--

Second edit, going even further, this only happens inside functions

This works

```
exec("""
def f(n):
    print("end") if n == 1 else f(n-1)

f(10)""")
```

But this gives me the same error as above

```
def foo():
    exec("""
def f(n):
    print("end") if n == 1 else f(n-1)

f(10)""")


foo()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Are you sure you didn't override `exec` or something?

Comment: After fixing a problem with parenthesis, I can reproduce your problem with `test_rec`. Adding `print(dir())` inside `fact` prints `['n']`.

Comment: Hi @Jasmijn what error with parenthesis? I'm not overriding exec

Comment: `"""), "<string>", "exec")))` should be `""")), "<string>", "exec"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `exec` with the default locals, then binding local variables is undefined behavior. That includes `def`, which binds the new function to a local variable.

Also, functions defined inside `exec` can't access closure variables, which `fact` would be.

The best way to avoid these problems is to not use `exec`. The second best way is to provide an explicit namespace:

```
namespace = {}
exec(whatever, namespace)
```

Comment: Thanks user2357112 supports Monica, BTW nice nick. Is there any reason for that? I'm creating a new syntax and using ast module create an AST. Then I use exec to test the code but in this case it doesn't work

Comment: Yeap, using `exec("...", {})` works fine while `exec("...", {}, {})` dont. But it's okay, I need the first one only Thank you user2357112 supports Monica